# Using bindToController without a template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to learn how isolated scope, bindToController and controllerAs work.

If I make a directive with an isolated scope and a template, it works as expected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function directiveTest() {
            function CtrlTest() {
                this.foo = "honk";
                this.clearFoo = function() {
                    this.foo='';
                };
            }
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                scope: {
                    label : '@',
                    lg : '@'
                },
                bindToController : true,
                controller: CtrlTest,
                controllerAs: 'ctrlTest',
                template: '<label>\n    {{ ctrlTest.label }}\n    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrlTest.foo"/>\n</label>\n<button ng-click="ctrlTest.clearFoo()">Clear</button>\n\n<div>{{ ctrlTest.foo }}</div>\n\n<div ng-show="ctrlTest.foo.length> ctrlTest.lg">\n    Long string !\n</div>\n'
            };
        }
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.directive('dirTest',[directiveTest]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <dir-test label="Type something now:" lg="7">
    </dir-test>
</body>
</html>
```

I was trying to do the same without the template, but I can't make it work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function directiveTest() {
            function CtrlTest() {
                this.foo = "honk";
                this.clearFoo = function() {
                    this.foo='';
                };
            }
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                scope: {
                },
                bindToController : true,
                controller: CtrlTest,
                controllerAs: 'ctrlTest'
            };
        }
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.directive('dirTest',[directiveTest]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <dir-test>
        <label>
            Type something again :
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrlTest.foo"/>
        </label>
        <button ng-click="ctrlTest.clearFoo()">Clear</button>

        <div>{{ ctrlTest.foo }}</div>

        <div ng-show="ctrlTest.foo.length>7">
            Long string !
        </div>
    </dir-test>
</body>
</html>
```

However that works if I set scope to true instead of an isolate scope.

Can someone explain to me how to make the 2nd example work, or if it's not possible, why ?

Comment: This is just how isolated scope works. The content inside the <dir-test> tags does not get the scope for the dirTest directive. Only the content in your template gets the scope from the directive. Any reason you don't want to use a template?

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way to make a directive where the content may slightly change. Probably there is no point in making an isolate scope in that case. I'm just experimenting and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Flip the values of `bindToController` and `scope` around.

```
{
    ....
    scope: true,
    bindToController: {}
    ...
}
```

I have just hit the same issue over the weekend, and made a simple complete example here: [`bindToController` Not Working? Here’s the right way to use it! (Angular 1.4+)](http://gurustop.net/blog/2015/08/31/blog/2015/08/31/bindtocontroller-angularjs-1-4)